# JAVA: Creating a new array that has the same number of rows/columns in parameter?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how arrays work, specifically when the array is not given a specific size. For example, if I'm given the code:

```
public int [][] someMethodHere(int [][] myNewArray) { 
//code here
}
```

I want to know how I can create another array within the method with the same number of rows and columns in the parameter (WITHOUT just adding in some numerical value in the parameter and then just writing the same value in the new array. Thanks!)

Comment: You simply get the array's length property and use it when making the new array.

Comment: This is a one-dimensional array; what do you mean by "rows and columns"?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add in another bracket

Answer (score 0):

An array has a fixed size that you set when you create the array.

This is different to many other data structures like `List` or `Map` that are "smart" and can handle resizing themselves when the need arises.

So when you create an array you must tell the compiler how big it is:

```
// create the original array with 10 slots
int[] originalArray = new int[10];
```

If you want to create a new array of the same size, you can use the `length` property of the `Array` type.

```
// create a new array of the same size as the original array
int[] newArray = new int[originalArray.length];
```

In your case of a 2-dimensional array, you could do it like this:

```
// create the original array
int[][] originalArray = new int[10][20];

// create a new array of the same size as the original array
int[][] newArray = new int[originalArray.length][originalArray[0].length];
```

Notice that when specifying the length of the second dimension, I get the length of the first element in the original array. This works as long as all the rows have the same length.

If the rows are of different length you could set the length of each row in the new array by iterating over the first dimension of the array like this:

```
// create a new array where the first dimension is the same size as the original array
int[][] newArray = new int[originalArray.length][];

// set the size of the 2nd dimension on a per row basis
for(int i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
    newArray[i] = new int[originalArray[i].length];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make a copy of the array and clear the new array.

```
public static int[][] someMethodHere(int[][] src) {
    int length = src.length;
    int[][] target = new int[length][src[0].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        System.arraycopy(src[i], 0, target[i], 0, src[i].length);
        Arrays.fill(target[i], 0);
    }
    return target;
}
```

Comment: This creates a bunch of null rows, no columns.

Comment: Now it makes even less sense. You're creating a clean array, then copying the data from the source array and immediately clearing it.